# AMD-V is not available (VERR_SVM_NO_SVM)

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

Virtualbox and running virtual machines have worked previously. I cannot remember what changed for it to not work anymore.

Whenever I try to launch or create a new virtual machine this error pops up:

`AMD-V is not available (VERR_SVM_NO_SVM).`

[image: AMD-V is not available (VERR_SVM_NO_SVM).]

I have tried making new 64-bit ubuntu and 32-bit ubuntu. My existing VM also get that error. Same error always. I have tried reinstall virtualbox but that didn't help.

Setup:

- Ryzen 7 1700x with Windows 10.
- SVM is enabled in the bios settings.
- I have Hyper-v turned off as other answers have pointed out.

[image: Hyper-V is turned off]

I am aware of possible duplicates but those answers was not satisfactory:

- [“AMD-V is not available” even when Virtualization is enabled in the bios](https://superuser.com/questions/1016463/amd-v-is-not-available-even-when-virtualization-is-enabled-in-the-bios)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try :

- To ensure Hyper-V is totally disabled, enter in elevated Command Prompt:

  ```
  bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
  ```
- Run `gpedit.msc` and go to
  *Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Device Guard > Turn on Virtualization Based Security*, and set to *Disabled*.
  Do the same for *CredentialGuard*.
- Check *Windows Defender Security Center > Device Security > Core Isolation Details*,
  that it is turned off.

Comment: I'm getting an error when creating a 32-bit ubuntu but I don't think they are releated. Also using a prebuilt vm works as it should. Thanks for your answer. I think specifically the `gpedit` part did the trick. I previously had done `bcedit`. Also I did a reboot, but don't know of it's effect.

Comment: Please, please, please @Microsoft to fix this!

Comment: I think I had to also restart the pc, at least

Comment: I cannot find the credential guard. There is a credential delegation. Windows version 1909.18363

Comment: i used `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` and rebooted now virtualbox works again

Comment: Same here, just done the cmd command and restarted.

Answer (score 3):

This problem happened on my Windows 10 build 1903 after I enabled Windows Sandbox in Windows features. It was solved after I uninstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to disable "Windows Hypervisor Platform" besides "Hyper-V" in Windows Features. Reboot and it should work without disabling anything in BIOS / bcdedit.

Comment: VirtualBox supports Windows Hypervisor Platform.  Why is it required to disable this particular feature?

Comment: @Ramhound I have no idea tbh, I got the same error as the OP, the only change I did was disabling this and it magically worked. It may be a bug or a coincidence.

Answer (score -1):

For me it helped it looks like to disable  and enable  virtualization in bios **Edit:** it's very important point, however I did not take my time to resimulate it.
UEFI bios type I have, -> Advanced -> cpu features ->  SVM item (this is named virtualization in UEFI BIOS on ADM cpus other cpus and bioses its VTX).

I also used above `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: I can't help myself but comment, why I got minus point?, I did this comment tbh not for you, but for me guys, as it helped me, so I presume it works. I used the above command, but not even restart helped, I might try to reproduce. So disabling and enabling, might be sometimes the case to clear some cache I assume.

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it's a comment and does not answer the author's question.  The author had already enabled SVM according to their answer.

Comment: ok, although the question is too much generalized, I did not find another question of its kind on Google, the question is generalized almost to the extent of saying 'Your computer could not start', so needs various solutions. I don't think it's a comment, I mentioned the chosen answer just because it did not work for me. Maybe it was a misunderstanding but I tried it at least 10 times, enabling alone did not help, I had to disable and reenable (sort of restart) in combination with using the bcedit command. The author mentioned had it enabled like me prior, not 'reenabling'.

Comment: The author accepted an answer 2 years ago.  It sounds you had a similar issue but the same issue as the author.  I still believe this to be commentary.

Comment: ok thanks, I take your point then, my logical deduction was like, enabling it in the bios was not mentioned the slightest in the chosen answer, I had a different comment there, if it was I would comment to add to it as a supplement. To be honest, I checked your profile and you are a very loyal contributor, so it adds weight to your reasoning even more, anyway I will leave it up to general publicity free will (like you did, thanks) might help some edge cases or not, as I am not knowledgable to explain my solution now as its a low/"hardware" layer.but deal with the answer, comments as you prefer